# Different classes for different JPanels

Tags: java, class, jpanel

I am a Beginner in Java. I have looked all over the place for an answer to my question, but could not find any, or they were to complex for me at this stage of my Java knowledge.

What Planning to do is to create a program on the way of my learning, it will be quite a bit of code and would like to keep things organized.

I have a class where I want to store the mainPanel, where then I would like to add other JPanels which are stored in other classes (on button click (not with a cardLayout)).

My code is probably full of errors, I hope you can help me.

Here is my main class:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class TestTool {
    public static void main(String[] args){

        Test1 frame = new Test1();

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    }
}
```

Then I have another class where I want to store the mainPanel and load other panels from different classes:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Test1 extends JFrame {

    public Test1(){
        testPanel();
    }

    public void testPanel(){
        setTitle("Test Tool");

        TestPanel1 te = new TestPanel1();

        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
        mainPanel.add(te.pan());

    }
}
```

On the next class I have a different panel which I am then trying to load into the mainPanel:

```
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class TestPanel1 {

    private JPanel panel1;

    public TestPanel1(){

        JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
        JLabel label1 = new JLabel("panel 1");
        panel1.add(label1);
        JButton button1 = new JButton("button 1");
        panel1.add(button1);

    }

    public JPanel pan(){

        return panel1;

    }

}
```

Is there anyway I can do it like this? or am I doing it completely wrong?

Thank you

Comment: Suggestions: 1) You need to add your mainPanel to the JFrame's contentPane for it to be visualized. Just calling `add(mainPanel);` would be enough to do this. 2) Why is TestPanel1 extending a JPanel when you never use the class as a JPanel? I would not have it extend JPanel and instead just use the JPanel that is returned. 3) Have you gone through the Java tutorials yet? They're a great resource for learning the rudiments of Java and for learning the underpinnings of the Swing GUI library.

Comment: I'm not clear what you want to have happen when a button is clicked, as you have no Action or ActionListener code added.

Comment: I did not add any actionlistener yet, but I want to be able to click a button and go to a different JPanel which is in a different class.

Comment: Again, unclear. What do you mean by "go to a different JPanel"? If you mean swap JPanels, then yes, by all means use a CardLayout (and get rid of the "not with a CardLayout" statement). If something else, then please elaborate. Clear details will help.

Comment: I could go for a cardLayout, but can you place components in a cardLayout like in a gridBagLayout? The gridBagLayout was the one I was looking for and already checked out a tutorial. On button click I wanted to remove one panel and add another one to the mainPanel.

Comment: @SergeInácio You place container/panels within a `CardLayout`, each  container/panel can have it's own layout and sub components which can have there own layouts again...

Comment: Thank you @MadProgrammer :) sounds good. Is there somewhere I can find a simple example code to do this? I cannot find any.

Comment: [How to Use CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest making the TestPanel class extend the JPanel class and in your constructor call the superconstructor and then do what you need.